# Login form css is messed up in RTL

Tags: login, css

I have a problem regarding the login form in Joomla, it is displayed quite well when the selected language is English (LTR), but whenever I change it to RTL (Arabic or anything), the CSS gets messed up.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I am mainly a backend engineer, so this thing is bothering me alot.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't seem to see any issue. What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell the exact reason without looking at your template, but as you say, it's highly likely it's a CSS issue. Probably, your template does not float the labels for the input fields correctly.

You can load a different CSS file based on language direction. This is usually done using a PHP if/else statement like this:

```
    <?php if($this->direction == 'rtl') : ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template_rtl.css" type="text/css" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Try targeting the input labels using CSS, and set them to `float:right;`.